# How to create new non-blocking processes in python? (examples does not work)

Tags: python-3.x

i want to do a job as fast as possible so i should paralelize it using processes (not threads because of GIL). My problem is that i cant start the processes at the sametime, it always start p1, when p1 ends, p2, and so on... how can i start all my processes at the same time? My simplified code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
def work(data,num):
   if(num==0):
        time.sleep(5)
   print("starts:",num)
   ******heavy works that lasts random seconds to be done*****************
   print("ends",num)

**********
for k in range(0,2):
  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work(data,k))
  p.daemon=True
  p.start()
```

result:

```
starts 0
ends 0
starts 1
ends 1
starts 2
ends 2
```

What i expected:

```
starts 0
starts 1
starts 2
ends 1 or 2
ends 1 or 2
ends 0 (because of time.sleep)
```

why my scripts waits always until the first process is finished to start the next one?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, making your program parallel/concurrent does not always make it **faster** as *[Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)* suggests

Secondly, you want to use the `join()` method in order to execute them concurrently, furthermore, you need to pass the arguments with the `args` parameter, because what you are doing is calling the whole function each time, and blocking each run with `time.sleep(5)`, without waiting on one process to finish as such:

```py
    process_pool = []
    for k in range(0, 5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work, args=('you_data', k))
        p.daemon = True
        process_pool.append(p)
    for process in process_pool:
        process.start()
    for process in process_pool:
        process.join()
```